# Javascript detection script

Tags: javascript

I need a JS detection script that will redirect users who do not have JS enabled to a different page without JS.

Comment: +1 for the laugh out loud paradox. (Good question though.)

Comment: I know it was a paradox :D

The noscript method worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kind of a paradox, isn't it? The answer can't be a script, since no scripts would be executed if JS is not enabled.

You can embed HTML inside a noscript tag, and this content will only be included if JS is not enabled.

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/no_js.html/"></noscript>
```